# Error al compilar trigger en MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Básicamente tengo 3 tablas con el siguiente formato:

Cursos

```
+---------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| idCurso | nombre             | idperiodo | creditos |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1       | Estrutura de datos | EM18      |        6 |
```

Grupos

```
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
| idgrupo | idprofesor | idcurso | idperiodo |
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
|       1 | 7          | 12      | EM19      |
```

Inscripciones

```
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
| idInscripcion | cargo | status   | matricula | idgrupo |
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
|             1 |  2000 | CURSANDO | 01329173  |       1 |
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Y necesito hacer un trigger que obtenga los créditos del curso y después calcular lo que se le va a cobrar al alumno en la inscripción por curso, todo esto despues de haber hecho el insert, por ejemplo, una materia tiene un costo de un crédito y el valor por crédito es de 1000, por lo tanto, se le cobraría 1000 en la inscripción.

Este es mi trigger:

```
  DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER credit_calc
AFTER INSERT ON inscripcion
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
  DECLARE credit_old INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE new_credit INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;

  /* Aqui obtengo los creditos de la tabla curso y los almaceno en credit_old */
  SET credit_old = (SELECT curso.creditos FROM inscripcion INNER JOIN grupo ON inscripcion.idInscripcion = grupo.idgrupo INNER JOIN curso ON inscripcion.idInscripcion=curso.idCurso where inscripcion.idInscripcion=new.idInscripcion);
  /* calculo el valor real de los creditos */
  SET new_credit=credit * 5000;

  /* le hago un update a la tabla inscripcion con el calculo hecho previamente */
  UPDATE inscripcion SET cargo = @new_credit WHERE inscripcion.idInscripcion = new.idInscripcion;
  
END; $$
```

Alguna idea de por que no funciona mi trigger?

Comment: cual es el error que te arroja?, por ahora solo puedo ver que credit_old al no tener un limit puede recibir mas de un dato, arregla eso

Comment: Me arroja este error : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server" y como puedo arreglar lo del limit?

Comment: pues con `limit 1` `SELECT curso.creditos FROM inscripcion INNER JOIN grupo ON inscripcion.idInscripcion = grupo.idgrupo INNER JOIN curso ON inscripcion.idInscripcion=curso.idCurso where inscripcion.idInscripcion=new.idInscripcion limit 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independientemente de que en tu código cobras el crédito a 5000 y combinas las tablas por campos que no corresponden, te sugiero el siguiente disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_inscripcion
  BEFORE INSERT ON inscripcion
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.cargo=(
    SELECT SUM(creditos)*1000 cargo
      FROM grupo JOIN curso  USING(idcurso)
      WHERE idgrupo=NEW.idgrupo
  );
```

Que daría este resultado:

```
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
| idInscripcion | cargo | status   | matricula | idgrupo |
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
|             1 |  6000 | CURSANDO | 1329173   |       1 |
+---------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE curso(
  idcurso int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  idperiodo varchar(15),
  creditos int
  );
CREATE TABLE grupo(
  idgrupo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idprofesor int,
  idcurso int,
  idperiodo varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE inscripcion(
  idInscripcion int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cargo int,
  `status`  varchar(15),
  matricula varchar(15),
  idgrupo int
  );
INSERT INTO curso (idcurso, nombre, idperiodo, creditos) VALUES
  (1,'Estructura de datos','EM18',6);
INSERT INTO grupo (idgrupo, idprofesor, idcurso, idperiodo) VALUES
  (1,7,1,'EM19');
INSERT INTO inscripcion (idInscripcion, cargo, status, matricula, idgrupo) VALUES
  (NULL,2000,'CURSANDO',01329173,1);
```